# heatmap in Julia : why is there a transpose between the terminal and the IDE?

Tags: plot, plotly, julia, heatmap

I'm unsure why the heatmap outputed by the following minimal working example

```
using Plots

plotlyjs()

List_x = [1, 2, 3]
List_y = [1, 2]
List_f = [0 0 0; 1 2 3]

my_plot = heatmap(List_x, List_y, List_f,
                    xlabel = "x axis", ylabel = "y_axis")

display(my_plot)

readline()
```

depends on whether I run the code from my IDE (either VSCode or Atom), or from the terminal with

```
>>> julia MWE.jl
```

In the IDE case, I get

[Figure produced by the MWE if run from IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x6Fd.png)

And in the terminal case I get

[Figure produced by the MWE if run from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcW9E.png)

As you can see, there is a transpose between the two cases. I would like to always have the IDE behavior, can I do something about it?

Comment: I posted the code in the REPL and it gives me the terminal outcome, which looks like the wrong one to me (x axis has 2 pixel values and y axis has 3 (miscropped) pixel values, but it should be the other way around). Simplifying the plot lines to `heatmap(List_f)` also does this.

Comment: This looks to be a bug with Plots' wrapping of PlotlyJS. The IDEs are requesting a different format of the plot, which renders it correctly.  Please report it [on Plots' issue tracker](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug&template=bug.md&title=%5BBUG%5D).

Comment: Ok, I've just reported it, so the discussion will continue there: https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/3940

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior was due to a bug reported in https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/3940, fixed in https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/pull/3953, and released in Plots.jl v1.24.2. On the most recent version, the REPL (terminal) plot now looks like:

[image: test figure on REPL]